# Swift 3 Howto parse json from Alamofire into a model

Tags: swift3, alamofire

I can't parse a json response from an Alamofire query into a model. I have this model code. What am I doing wrong? I am using Swift 3 in Xcode 8.3

```
enum SerializationError: Error {
    case missing(String)
    case invalid(String, Any)
}


    struct Thing {
        var id: String
        var name: String
    }

    extension Thing {
        init(json: [String: Any]) throws {

            guard let id = json["id"] as? String else {
                throw SerializationError.missing("id")
            }

            guard let name = json["name"] as? String else {
                throw SerializationError.missing("name")
            }

            self.id = id

            self.name = name
        }
    }
```

Then in my controller I have

```
func parseData(jsonData: [String: Any]) {

    var model = [Thing]()

    let things = jsonData["things"] as! [[String: Any]]

    for thing in things {

        do {

            let aThing = try Thing(json: thing)

            model.append(aThing)

        } catch let error {

            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

I always get an error. I know that the error isn't about the json response as I have checked it carefully and had extra code in there to test that the elements are present.

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (MyApp.SerializationError error 0.)
```

Comment: I tested using your code and it run well. Can you share what your json response is?

Comment: I need to obfuscate my code as you can see by my question. The result of `model.count` is 0

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: `let aThing = try Thing(json: thing)`

Comment: I think your json is in wrong format, please check it again.